# Cannot merge several input datasets in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am the new one in ModelBuilder, so have faced some troubles with merging my resulted feature class with my set of input dataset.

Could you please help me to find the mistake?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your Question to try and make what you are asking clearer, please?  For example, the six model elements at lower right seem to be irrelevant to your Question so I recommend that you make a new test model without them and describe the precise steps (with all parameter values) that you use to do so.  It looks like you have renamed the tools and variables from their default names which leaves us guessing what they might be.

Comment: I'm with PolyGeo, I've got no idea what that's trying to achieve. Can you explain what your model is trying to do and what the inputs you have are. All I see here is preconditions, tools and unqualified names.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I am trying to create the empty point feature class, then add fields to it and afterwards merge it with the other shapefiles, So in the end everything is in one shapefile, which i have created at the beginning. The question is it actually possible?

Comment: Yes, I've done it many times. The model should be more linear with the outputs feeding into the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:
[image]

Each result feeds into the next input, preconditions (dotted lines) aren't required for a simple operation like this as the script will run left to right.

To add a field use the [Add field tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000047000000). If you have multiple add fields, which is fairly normal, link them together with the output from one add field feeding into the next add field:

[image]
The merge tool can't be used to do what you want; the [Append](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000050000000) tool is the one that will add existing features to the new feature class.